# How to increase the angle of italic text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a logo using html css. Can we increase the angle of *italic text* using css or javascript?

Comment: *no*. Make a logo using Photoshop instead.

Comment: No way. Such things are still best put into an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page comes up at the top in search engines, and yet no real answer is provided. Yes, today this is possible with pure CSS3 using skew - check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7999132

However, instead of positive 30deg values from above answer, to simulate fine italic angle you need to use negative degree values (-5deg for example).

Works & looks great in all modern browsers which support skew. You can combine regular italic style with skew to achieve even better rendering (worked in my case).

Answer (score 7):

The angle depends on the font you are using. The font designer has to draw the italic version manually. You can't change that automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the **skew transform** property of CSS instead of using italics. It may help you.

For e.g.:

```
<div style="transform: skewX(-10deg)">Sample italic text</div>
```

P.S.: This method will help you change the angle of italics of text, but for the case of designing the logo, you'll definitely need illustrator for excellence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a skew transform in Firefox, Safari and Chrome. Nothing else is going to support it, and you shouldn't screw around with a font designer's work for a logo design unless you know more about typography than they did anyway. Nobody designs logos in HTML and nobody wants to look at logos in email.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with CSS. You could try to switch to another font on `i`'s and `em`'s that has more slanted letters but I don't think that'll help you.

And if you're designing a logo, why are you doing it with CSS? That's what you have Photoshop and/or Illustrator for.

Comment: i'm designing a logo for client to show his logo in his email newsletters if user or email client or web mail keeps images disabled by default

Answer (score 0):

HTML/CSS is the wrong tool for this. Use Illustrator or that kind of software. Or look for a designer.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own font or modify an open source font using a free font-editing tool such as [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/).

Edit: I see that this is for e-mail with images disabled. Sorry, but it's not possible at all in this case, as most e-mail clients other than new versions of Thunderbird don't support @font-face CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

`font-style: oblique 20deg;`

Use whatever you want instead 20.
Usefull to decrease the italic angle aswell.
(edit : works only on Firefox and Thunderbird, thx to MrLister)

Comment: You should note that this currently only works in Firefox and Thunderbird.