# Adding More Slant To Italic Text

Tags: css

I was curious as to if you can impact italic text with more of a slant with CSS? If so, how can this be accomplished?

Comment: maybe with css3 scew, but other than that it's based on the browser's implementation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can simulate a custom slant with CSS3 skew transformations (although it will not look as great as a real italic font).

Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<p class="slant">Some text</p>
```

CSS

```
.slant {
    -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(30deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(30deg, 0deg);
    -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(30deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(30deg, 0deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(30deg, 0deg);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your mention that this will not make a font look as good as a normal italic. Good solution, as well.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use

```
font-style: oblique 50deg;
```

(you can change 50 to what angle you want)

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score 5):

With standard `font-style` in CSS, it is not possible to customise the `italic` state.

This is up to the browsers own preference and the fonts italic state.

Comment: "Purely" up to the browser? Does it have nothing to do with the font itself?