# combining font-style:italic & font-weight:bold cause reversed slant in FF

Tags: html, css, fonts, italic

Take a look at the text under the full width images here >> http://ghostowncrew.com/ ; 
**In Firefox**, the title is slanted right, and the text after is slanted left.
The difference is a font-weight: bold on the title, but it also reverses the slant direction!

i was unable to replicate it in this JSBIN >> http://jsbin.com/uNUMEQuy/

Have you ever encountered a similar issue?

thanks!

Comment: What text under what images?

Comment: maybe this answer will be of use to you:    
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7999132/2460773

also, we need to know where the problem accures, what browser are you using, etc..

Comment: im not looking to simulate a slant or patch a standard italicized text..  Just want it to be as it should!
@Pete i edited to add the link..

Comment: @adeer, everything slants to the right for me.  Which browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox is the troublemaker.

Comment: looks just fine on firefox as well.

Comment: not for me..  http://imgur.com/Afj9faQ   i'll test another version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a browser issue. Tested many other browser, and the same on a different computer, and all was fine.